# Custom Json Serializer, within custom json serializer

Tags: java, jackson, mapper

First, I have:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;

    @JsonSerialize(using=SSNJsonSerializer.class)
    private SSN ssn;

}
```

This works..

Now I have a 'wrapper classe' like:

```
public class Response {

    private Integer total;

    @JsonSerializer(contentUsing=ResponseJsonSerializer.class)
    private List<Object> itens;
    private Boolean success;

}
```

itens can be a List of person. But I can't serialize all fields (of Person). ResponseJsonSerializer know what can be write;

Insite ResponseJsonSerializer, I have:

```
jgen.writeObjectField(name, field.get(value) );
```

But console say: `No serializer found for class ...SSN and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )`

How can I, inside ResponseJsonSerializer, use the serializers declared on the fields?

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: @Jaap reading annotation (@JsonSerializer) on each attribute